# How Can I Properly put this html in my PHP script

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add my printerfriendly button to all of my posts under my header. this is the HTML of the button:

```
    <script>var pfHeaderImgUrl = '';var pfHeaderTagline = '';var pfdisableClickToDel = 0;var pfHideImages = 0;var pfImageDisplayStyle = 'right';var pfDisablePDF = 0;var pfDisableEmail = 0;var pfDisablePrint = 0;var pfCustomCSS = '';var pfBtVersion='1';(function(){var js, pf;pf = document.createElement('script');pf.type = 'text/javascript';if('https:' == document.location.protocol){js='https://pf-cdn.printfriendly.com/ssl/main.js'}else{js='http://cdn.printfriendly.com/printfriendly.js'}pf.src=js;document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pf)})();</script><a href="http://www.printfriendly.com" style="color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none;" class="printfriendly" onclick="window.print();return false;" title="Printer Friendly and PDF"><img style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;" src="http://cdn.printfriendly.com/button-print-grnw20.png" alt="Print Friendly and PDF"/>
    </a>
```

As for now, the example I placed in the HTML printerfriendly code that was generated in my side bar that you can see here :

http://iamdentistry.com/archive/dentistry/about-dental-night-guards/

I do not know how to move this button to where I want. I want to place it in the same line as the `Leave A Response` button under the posts header to the far right.

I asked the author of the theme and all they told me was that I need to add the code to the content.php file of my theme which is this :

```
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php hybrid_entry_class(); ?>">

<?php if ( is_singular( get_post_type() ) ) : ?>

    <?php
    $format = get_post_format();
    get_template_part( 'post-header', $format );
    ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if (
                fearless_get_option( 'singular_featured_image_enabled' )
                && 'audio' != $format
                && 'gallery' != $format
                && 'video' != $format
            ) {
                fearless_post_thumbnail();
            }
        ?>

        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php
        printf(
            apply_atomic_shortcode(
                'entry_byline',
                '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( 'Posted by [entry-author] on [entry-published] in [entry-terms taxonomy="category"] | %1$s [entry-comments-link before=" | "]', 'fearless' ) . '</div>'
            ),
            sprintf(
                _n(
                    '1 View',
                    '%1$s Views',
                    get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Views', true ),
                    'fearless'
                ),
                get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Views', true )
            )
        );
        ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) get_template_part( 'review-box' ); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . '<span class="before">' . __( 'Pages:', 'fearless' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_meta', '<div class="entry-meta">' . __( '[entry-terms before="Posted in " taxonomy="category"] [entry-terms before="| Tagged "]', 'fearless' ) . '</div>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

<?php else : ?>

    <?php global $fearless_blogroll_layout; ?>

    <?php fearless_post_thumbnail( $fearless_blogroll_layout['thumbnail_size'] ); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_byline', '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( '[entry-author] / [entry-published]', 'fearless' ) . '</div>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( $fearless_blogroll_layout['excerpt_length'] ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php echo fearless_get_the_excerpt( $fearless_blogroll_layout['excerpt_length'] ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . '<span class="before">' . __( 'Pages:', 'fearless' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( '1col-thumb' != $fearless_blogroll_layout['style'] ) : ?>
        <p class="more-link-wrapper"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more button"><?php _e( 'Read More &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

    </article><!-- .hentry -->
```

----- Dave this is how I attempted what you asked :

```
    <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_byline', '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( '[entry-author] / [entry-published]', 'fearless' ) . '<script>var pfHeaderImgUrl = '';var pfHeaderTagline = '';var pfdisableClickToDel = 0;var pfHideImages = 0;var pfImageDisplayStyle = 'right';var pfDisablePDF = 0;var pfDisableEmail = 0;var pfDisablePrint = 0;var pfCustomCSS = '';var pfBtVersion='1';(function(){var js, pf;pf = document.createElement('script');pf.type = 'text/javascript';if('https:' == document.location.protocol){js='https://pf-cdn.printfriendly.com/ssl/main.js'}else{js='http://cdn.printfriendly.com/printfriendly.js'}pf.src=js;document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pf)})();</script><a href="http://www.printfriendly.com" style="color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none;" class="printfriendly" onclick="window.print();return false;" title="Printer Friendly and PDF"><img style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;" src="http://cdn.printfriendly.com/button-print-grnw20.png" alt="Print Friendly and PDF"/></a></div>' ); 
    ?>
```

---------------Christopher Pecoraro , this was my attempt:

```
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php hybrid_entry_class(); ?>">

<?php if ( is_singular( get_post_type() ) ) : ?>

    <?php
    $format = get_post_format();
    get_template_part( 'post-header', $format );
    ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if (
                fearless_get_option( 'singular_featured_image_enabled' )
                && 'audio' != $format
                && 'gallery' != $format
                && 'video' != $format
            ) {
                fearless_post_thumbnail();
            }
        ?>

        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
        $link_text = '<script>var pfHeaderImgUrl = \'\';var pfHeaderTagline = \'\';var pfdisableClickToDel = 0;var pfHideImages = 0;var pfImageDisplayStyle = \'right\';var pfDisablePDF = 0;var pfDisableEmail = 0;var pfDisablePrint = 0;var pfCustomCSS = \'\';var pfBtVersion=\'1\';(function(){var js, pf;pf = document.createElement(\'script\');pf.type = \'text/javascript\';if(\'https:\' == document.location.protocol){js=\'https://pf-cdn.printfriendly.com/ssl/main.js\'}else{js=\'http://cdn.printfriendly.com/printfriendly.js\'}pf.src=js;document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(pf)})();</script><a href="http://www.printfriendly.com" style="color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none;" class="printfriendly" onclick="window.print();return false;" title="Printer Friendly and PDF"><img style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;" src="http://cdn.printfriendly.com/button-print-grnw20.png" alt="Print Friendly and PDF"/></a>';
    printf(
        apply_atomic_shortcode(
            'entry_byline',
            '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( 'Posted by [entry-author] on [entry-published] in [entry-terms taxonomy="category"] | %1$s [entry-comments-link before=" | "]', 'fearless' ) . $link_text . '</div>'
        ),
            sprintf(
                _n(
                    '1 View',
                    '%1$s Views',
                    get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Views', true ),
                    'fearless'
                ),
                get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Views', true )
            )
        );
        ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) get_template_part( 'review-box' ); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . '<span class="before">' . __( 'Pages:', 'fearless' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_meta', '<div class="entry-meta">' . __( '[entry-terms before="Posted in " taxonomy="category"] [entry-terms before="| Tagged "]', 'fearless' ) . '</div>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

<?php else : ?>

    <?php global $fearless_blogroll_layout; ?>

    <?php fearless_post_thumbnail( $fearless_blogroll_layout['thumbnail_size'] ); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_byline', '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( '[entry-author] / [entry-published]', 'fearless' ) . '</div>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( $fearless_blogroll_layout['excerpt_length'] ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php echo fearless_get_the_excerpt( $fearless_blogroll_layout['excerpt_length'] ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . '<span class="before">' . __( 'Pages:', 'fearless' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( '1col-thumb' != $fearless_blogroll_layout['style'] ) : ?>
        <p class="more-link-wrapper"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more button"><?php _e( 'Read More &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

    </article><!-- .hentry -->
```

Comment: I would paste the  buttons code in a separate file and use the`require` statement to print it into the html where ever it is needed. If that is not enough I would add some css.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this (not elegant at all)?

replace:

```
<?php
        printf(
            apply_atomic_shortcode(
                'entry_byline',
                '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( 'Posted by [entry-author] on [entry-published] in [entry-terms taxonomy="category"] | %1$s [entry-comments-link before=" | "]', 'fearless' ) . '</div>'
            ),
```

with:

```
$link_text = '<script>var pfHeaderImgUrl = \'\';var pfHeaderTagline = \'\';var pfdisableClickToDel = 0;var pfHideImages = 0;var pfImageDisplayStyle = \'right\';var pfDisablePDF = 0;var pfDisableEmail = 0;var pfDisablePrint = 0;var pfCustomCSS = \'\';var pfBtVersion=\'1\';(function(){var js, pf;pf = document.createElement(\'script\');pf.type = \'text/javascript\';if(\'https:\' == document.location.protocol){js=\'https://pf-cdn.printfriendly.com/ssl/main.js\'}else{js=\'http://cdn.printfriendly.com/printfriendly.js\'}pf.src=js;document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(pf)})();</script><a href="http://www.printfriendly.com" style="color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none;" class="printfriendly" onclick="window.print();return false;" title="Printer Friendly and PDF"><img style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;" src="http://cdn.printfriendly.com/button-print-grnw20.png" alt="Print Friendly and PDF"/></a>';
        printf(
            apply_atomic_shortcode(
                'entry_byline',
                '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( 'Posted by [entry-author] on [entry-published] in [entry-terms taxonomy="category"] | %1$s [entry-comments-link before=" | "]', 'fearless' ) . $link_text . '</div>'
            ),
```

Comment: that dident work , the button showed but there was visible code all over the header area ? is there anything i need to fix, it almost worked

Comment: I don't know what apply_atomic_shortcode() is doing, although it appears that it calls do_shortcode().  If there are shortcodes inside this code, the string will be modified and that could cause problems.  As the others have suggested, could you add the text inside <script></script> in some context external to the printf?

Comment: yeah, I mean, it's pretty dodgy to put an entire script inside of an echo.  This is way way way not the right way to do this.  better would be to write an onclick function for the button. or put an empty div with an id and then put the content inside using innerhtml.

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your help. I mean I am clueless when it comes to PHP, is there another way you guys know that I can do this that does not involve php? and if not then, in you opinion, is there another location that is easier for me to add the print button that wont look out of place that goes around having to mess with the content PHP file ?

Answer (score 0):

Place your code where it says `[YOUR CODE HERE]`.  If you want to be lazy, just put it right in there.  Note that it is VERY IMPORTANT that you escape the single quotes in the code by putting a `\` in front of them

```
<?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_byline', '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( '[entry-author] / [entry-published]', 'fearless' ) . '[YOUR CODE HERE]</div>' ); ?>
```

You might want to do escape the single quotes this way:

```
$str = [YOUR CODE];
string addslashes ( string $str );
```

Then place `$str` in the code like ...`'fearless' ) . $str . '</div>'`
You could also just replace all the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: I have to warn that editing a template file like this is generally seen as bad practice, so try and avoid doing it in the future.

Comment: Why is it seen as bad practice ?

Comment: and also I tried this but i guess i did it wrong? I don't understand the / in front of single quotes reference. Look at my question again I added what you told me in code at the bottom so you can see how i did it wrong

Comment: It is bad practice because the logic of the website is generally separated from the design of the website, called the "view."  The most common paradigm that you see right now is called MVC, model-view-controller, but there are other ways of dividing it.  The files you are editing are template files, and shouldn't have logic in them.

Comment: the \ is an escape character.  if you text that is being quoted inside of a php echo, the text is delimited with double quotes " [content]".  If the content contains a double quote, the echo will end at that double quote, and you'll get an error.  to avoid this, either use only single-quotes inside of the double quotes, or escape the double quotes with a \

Comment: you should look around for how to make a button, then how to make an "onclick" event happen when you click that button.  Wrap the code you need into a function that is triggered when the button is clicked.  Put the button inside that echo call, and put the javascript for the onclick function at the bottom of the webpage in the footer inside of an onload event.

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your help. I mean I am clueless when it comes to PHP, is there another way you guys know that I can do this that does not involve php? and if not then, in you opinion, is there another location that is easier for me to add the print button that wont look out of place that goes around having to mess with the content PHP file ?

Comment: you should maybe invest a few all-nighters and learn the basics of php, it's pretty standard these days